How to "flatten" a table without using a cursor
I am trying to figure out how to do the following in SQL Server:
I have several rows in a census and would like to group them by resident and status (for starters).  I would like to group the consecutive records as one record showing the date range.  If there is a gap in dates, I would like there to be an additional record. For example:



Resident
Date
Status




John Doe
Jan 1
In


John Doe
Jan 2
In


John Doe
Jan 3
Hospital


John Doe
Jan 4
Hospital


***** Note the gap - no Jan 5 record ******




John Doe
Jan 6
Hospital


John Doe
Jan 7
Hospital


Mary Jane
Jan 1
In


Mary Jane
Jan 2
In


Mary Jane
Jan 3
In



I would to get the following result:



Resident
Begin Date
End Date
Status




John Doe
Jan 1
Jan 2
In


John Doe
Jan 3
Jan 4
Hospital


John Doe
Jan 6
Jan 7
Hospital


Mary Jane
Jan 1
Jan 3
In



I considered using a simple group by, but it won't take into account the gap in dates.  Formerly, I solved this problem by using a CURSOR, but I was wondering if I can tackle this without using one.  I have a feeling the solution will involve using a window and/or a pivot function, but haven't had success so far...

This is a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem. Possibly some useful answers in the first few results of this search. Look for ones that use ROW_NUMBER() to identify the beginning and end of contiguous ranges.

This is the solution I came up with after doing some research on SO:
WITH census_rows AS 
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentID, StatusCode ORDER BY CensusDate) AS RN_Status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ResidentID ORDER BY CensusDate) AS RN
    FROM [CensusTest]
)

SELECT ResidentID, StatusCode, MIN(CensusDate) AS BeginDate, MAX(CensusDate) AS EndDate
FROM census_rows
GROUP BY ResidentID, StatusCode, (RN_Status-RN), DATEDIFF(DAY, RN, CensusDate)


Plus 1 for putting in the effort to solve it yourself. You can accept it btw.

As Dale already pointed out, it is good practice to accept your own answer here, it will help others with the same problem to find it

I haven't tested, but for me this "simple" solution never worked for real life data.
